# Once I replace a party member, can I ever get him back?

Tags: baldurs-gate

Playing Baldur's Gate 1 in BGT

When I meet a new NPC and he asks me or I ask him to join the party, if my party is full, I can remove one of the previous members. But while some stay wherever I left them, others just leave out of the screen (Khalid for example), is there a way to get them back later on, if I want to, or is the NPC gone forever ?

It is kind of strange, since you can't event see the new guy's stats before making your decision.

Comment: its been forever since i played BG1. do they return to where you initially found them?

Comment: I seem to remember the party members staying where you leave them, but it has been 5+ years since I played.

Comment: If i recall correctly, you can tell them to stay put or to go to a certain place and wait for you there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is coming entirely from my memory, so please forgive me for any mistakes:

Most party members will stay where you put them (or if you say 'No' to them when they want to join). There are a number of exceptions though:

- If you remove Kivan, he stays gone for good.
- If you remove Shar-Teel, she stays gone for good.
- If you say 'No' to Jaheira and Khalid the first time, you can never get them again.
- Furthermore, if you kick out one of them, the other goes as well.
- If you say 'No' to Edwin with Dynaheir in your party, you can never get him again.
- If you say 'No' to Viconia the first time, you can never get her again.
- The same goes for Branwen and Yeslick
- If you make Xan leave by being rude, he's also gone forever.

Basically, whenever a party member leaves beacuse of arguments or disagreements they are gone for good.

Comment: You should note that if you kick out Minsc or Dynaheir, the other will leave as well, although they will reamin where you leave them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, Garrick will also be gone for good if you refuse him the first time.

Comment: This is new, useful information though. Maybe add 'in addition to the accepted answer'. Reminder: New users [cannot comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). The user that wrote the accepted answer has been inactive for 9 years. This would not be an acceptable edit for someone else to make/suggest; as it would change the content of the answer. Comments are second class citizens, so partial information like this should be in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Khalid and Jaheira go back to the Friendly-Arm-Inn if you kick out one of them.